# XE7 update 1 and iOS 8.1 simulator does not work

Tags: ios, xcode, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

With target set to iOS 8.1 Simulator in Delphi XE7, the application crashes. It deploys fine, it also runs, but the firemonkey splash screen remains on and never finishes loading. 
This happens with a plain new mobile application, only adding one "hello world" TLabel to the form.

This began to happen after I upgraded from XE6 to XE7 update 1, and at the same time upgraded XCode 5 to 6.1 (stupid to make do two major upgrades at the same time, because then I don't know which one caused the problem).

To solve it I opened XCode and installed the iOS 7.1 Simulator. The Hello World application is now run in 7.1 Simulator and works fine, but now it always runs in 7.1, even when I set the Target in Delphi to iOS 8.1 Simulator. Therefore I can no longer reproduce the first problem.

So I have two issues with XE7 upd1 and XCode 6.1:

1. Applications run in iOS 8.1 Simulator crashes
2. When iOS 7.1 Simulator is installed I can no longer run in the 8.1 Simulator

Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS simulator 8.1 not supported yet.