# Hotfix for Firemonkey for iOS 8 Simulator

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, simulator

Maybe anybody knows, how to use iOS 8 Simulator with Firemonkey?

Maybe Embarcadero already has a hotfix? If so, please, give a link.

Thanks.

**Updated:**

Thanks to @LU RD.

Here is the solution for XE8: http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/30221

Comment: I noticed that even when targeting iOS8, it always runs in the iOS7.1 simulator. However, I don't know what happens if there is only an iOS8 simulator available on the Mac?
Anyway, Embarcadero might only support iOS8 with Delphi XE8, which makes sense as you can no longer release an iOS app with XE7 anyway (since 1. feb where 64 bit i required).

Comment: @Hans, thanks. It's means that there is no solution for XE7 use iOS 8 simulator?

Comment: I asked the same question some time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971457/xe7-update-1-and-ios-8-1-simulator-does-not-work and AFAIK there is still no solution. You can deploy to an iOS8 device and you can use the Simulator 7.1, but not the Simulator 8

Comment: @Hans Depends, our deadline for that requirement is June 1st since we already have an App ID. February 1st was the deadline for new apps.

Comment: @JerryDodge Yes, two months more to go then all Delphi users targeting iOS MUST buy XE8 :-)

Comment: There is a hotfix for XE8 and the IOS 8 simulator, http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/30221.

Answer (score 0):

Delphi XE8 release notes state the following:

The iOS Simulator for the latest version of iOS (8.x) is not yet supported as a target platform for FireMonkey multi-device applications. You can, however, use the iOS simulator that is supported on iOS 7.