# Delphi XE8 error FMX.ListView

Tags: delphi, listview, firemonkey

I'm trying delphi XE 8 and I found that if I declare to use the library FMX.ListView gives me error (no load) when run on the iOS simulator. I have updated to the latest version XCode.

no problem:

```
   unit Unit2;

  interface

  uses
    System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
    FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs;

 type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
  private
   { Private declarations }
  public
   { Public declarations }
 end;

var
 Form2: TForm2;

 implementation

{$R *.fmx}

end.
```

error:

```
 unit Unit2;

 interface

uses
 System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes,  System.Variants,
 FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.ListView;

type
 TForm2 = class(TForm)
  private
   { Private declarations }
  public
   { Public declarations }
 end;

var
 Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

 end.
```

Does it happen to someone else this error?

Comment: loads the splash and then the application is closed

Comment: Hi All,

Can anyone help me? the error is:
Module Load: GLKit. No Debug Info. Base Address: $0A981000. Process dyld_sim (1702)

First chance exception at $00017A0C. Exception class EOSError with message

'System Error.  Code: 2.
No such file or directory'.

Process dyld_sim (1702)

Comment: Similar error reported here: https://plus.google.com/u/0/+JemerGaribay/posts/GBh4nyGpxTk.

Comment: Thank you, I eventually found that Embarcadero is still making the simulator to work properly. So...

Comment: See [Hotfix for Firemonkey for iOS 8 Simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29182684/576719) as well.