# Delphi XE8 Firemonkey iOS app crashing with just a TEdit

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I create a fresh iOS app, put a TEdit on it, and run it in the simulator and the program crashes. 
Remove the TEdit, run it, and it crashes.
Remove the FMX.Edit from the uses clause, run it, and it runs OK.

Has anyone got a solution to this?

thanks

Comment: Are you using any style sheets? What iOS version are you targeting and what version are you actually running it on? How does it "crash"? Any error messages?

Comment: No style sheets. iOS Simulator version 8.3.  OSX 10.10.3. The app flickers in the simulator and vanishes, it doesn't fire OnCreate.

Comment: I'm not sure about iOS, but I know I was fighting an issue in Android for a while, turned out one SDK path link was wrong, and there were no warnings indicating it was a wrong path.

Comment: You don't recall where they are in the IDE do you? And how did you figure it out - it's a pretty extraordinary thing to find.

Comment: Tools - Options - Environment Options - SDK Manager... I was facing similar anomalies and it turned out I had manually typed an incorrect path - it was a valid path but the wrong one.

Comment: Forced a re-download of the Simulator SDK, and it didn't make a difference. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: See [Delphi XE8 error FMX.ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29622963/576719). One of the links I gave there (https://plus.google.com/u/0/+JemerGaribay/posts/GBh4nyGpxTk), reports the same problem with TEdit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an error in the iOS simulator.

Reported as [RSP-10329 It's not working When I use Tedit, TListView on ios simulator](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-10329).

*Note: you have to be logged in to see the report.*

It affects the TEdit and TListView.

See also [Delphi XE8 error FMX.ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29622963/delphi-xe8-error-fmx-listview).